# SFMC API - Email Send Definition Not Implemented Error?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, c#

I'm trying to create and schedule an Email Send Definition via the c# SOAP API library and receiving a 42000 error.  The docs for that error are pretty vague.  Has anyone seen this before?  What caused it and what was the fix?  Thanks!

> 42000 ESD_NotImplementedException
>
> Type:
>
> Message: ESD_Not Implemented Exception
>
> Resolution:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what was causing the issue.  I was attempting to assign the "FromName" and "FromAddress" fields of the EmailSendDefinition.  Once I removed that, the error no longer occurred.  The assumption being the assignment of those two fields is not implemented.